# How to generate Facebook Share buttons to dynamically fetched content?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share

Here we have an article on how to add share buttons to a web page and it works:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

But on my website, I have a "Load more" button to fetch content dynamically and I have no idea how to add a Share button to newly generated items.

Obviously adding this div does not make any effect so I probably need to call some Facebook function to the newly created divs.

```
  <div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="https://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
    data-layout="button_count">
  </div>
```

Is anyone aware what is the name of this magic function?

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the solution here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples#dialogs
It shows how to trigger a share popup. It also gives more control over the look of the share button which is also what I've been looking for.